# how to consume an array within an array in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to consume an API whose response is like:-

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "2075/76",
            "2075-2094767",
            "2075/08/29",
            1466,
            "210003502",
            null,
            "गीता  श्रीस काउचा थापा",
            2418146,
            null,
            14224,
            "Production",
            1800,
            0,
            "2074/75",
            "2075/09/02",
            "Cash",
            null,
            "1",
            null,
            null,
            11019,
            "2018/12/17",
            0,
            "T",
            null,
            "2018/12/17"
        ],
        [
            "2075/76",
            "2075-2093892",
            "2075/08/28",
            1466,
            "210003502",
            null,
            "हेमन्त  बुढाथोकी",
            2417027,
            null,
            14224,
            "Production",
            1400,
            0,
            "2074/75",
            "2075/09/02",
            "Cash",
            null,
            "1",
            null,
            null,
            11019,
            "2018/12/17",
            0,
            "T",
            null,
            "2018/12/17"
        ]
]
}
```

I am using spring boot and rest template like this.

```
 @GetMapping("/consume")
    public void consumeApi(@RequestParam  String date) throws IOException {
        BankVoucherParams params = setVoucherParams(date);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String token = getBearerToken();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(token);


        HttpEntity<BankVoucherParams> request = new HttpEntity<BankVoucherParams>(params, headers);

        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(endpoint, request, String.class);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Object o = objectMapper.readValue(response,Object.class);




        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

in the above code I get the response in string form. I want to map every value to a pojo class and insert it into my database. For now I don't know how to map each of these array into my pojo class.

Comment: Refer This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556298/java-convert-list-of-object-array-to-a-pojo

Comment: This may help >>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109531/json-array-to-pojo

Answer (score 0):

If the pojo is available in that project scope you can simly parse the whole object like this:

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
```

where `Object` can be replaced by your pojo. So you would have something similar to

```
ResponseEntity<YourClass> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, YourClass.class);
```

If you need to map it you can use libraries like `Gson` or `Jackson.`

**EDIT:**
As mentioned below you do not receive key/value pairs. Because of that you need to use a mapper library like `Gson` or `Jackson`

Comment: I don't think it would work, because response does not have any key-value pair, but rather an object array

Comment: how do i map with gson or jackson ?

Comment: @sagarlimbu, I don't think you would be able to. Refer to the link mentioned in my comment to your question. You would need to have a similar implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the json string to a HashMap with key as "data" and value as

```
List<List<String>>
```

or

```
String[][].
```

Then iterate through the value and set it to a POJO.

If you would like to dynamically assign each position to a certain field of a POJO, you may wan to keep a mapping of position-field and uses reflection to set the fields. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html